# Find an example of an unbounded continuous function $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that is nonnegative and such that $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Find an example of an unbounded continuous function $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that is nonnegative and such that $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$. Note that this means that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist;  compare previous exercise. Hint: on the interval $[k, k+1]$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, define a function whose integral over this interval is less than say $2^{-k}$.

I guess the hint indicates that $\int_0^\infty f= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} f(x) < \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} < \infty$. But, I cannot find $f(x)$ such that $\int_k^{k+1} f(x) < 2^{-k}$, but limit does not exists. Could you provide one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$f_k(x)=\begin{cases}
     k &\text{if } k\leq x \leq k+\frac{2^{-k}}{k} \\
     0\text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

Then define

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)$$

Then

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+\frac{2^{-k}}{k}}k=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}=1<\infty$$

---

EDIT Added the continuity condition.

Define

$$g_k(x)=\begin{cases}
     \frac{2^{-k-1} (x-k)}{k^2} &\text{if } k\leq x \leq k+\frac{2^{-k-1}}{k} \\
     \frac{k^4+2^{-k-1} k (k-x)+2^{-2 (k+1)}}{k^3} &\text{if } k+\frac{2^{-k-1}}{k}\leq x \leq k+\frac{2^{-k}}{k} \\
     0\text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

Basically, these are just triangles that are under $f_k(x)$ that start at the beginning of the step function around $x=k$, hit the middle of the top of the step, and go back to the end of the step. This implies

$$g_k(x)\leq f_k(x)$$

Then for

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k(x)$$

we have

$$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty g_i(x)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)<\infty$$

Since $g(x)$ is continuous, we are done.

Comment: not continuous.

Comment: However one can replace it by a symmetric hat that peaks at a value of $k$ and whose base is the same length, then the same argument will go through.

Comment: Whoops, miffed that condition. Let me fix it

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be any continuous function such that $\int_0^1 f=I$ exists, $0<I<\infty$, and such that, for $x>1$ or $x<0$, $f(x)=0$. Furthermore, let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z_0^+}$, $(b_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z_0^+}$ be two sequences, such that $b_k\geq1$ for all $k$, $\limsup_{k\to\infty} a_k=\infty$, and $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{b_k}<\infty.$$

Examples of these are very easy to find. For example, $f$ a triangle, $a_k=k$, $b_k=2^k$ have the desired properties, as do many other sequences and functions.

Now, define $$g(x)=a_{\lfloor x\rfloor} \cdot f\left(b_{\lfloor x\rfloor}\{x\}\right),$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and $\{\cdot\}$ are the integer and fractional part, respectively. Clearly, $g$ will be continuous and unbounded, but $$\int_0^\infty g =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}g =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {a_k}{b_k}I<\infty.$$ $g$ is therefore a function satisfying the problem’s properties.